# array/list index out of range python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

the error I get is:

IndexError: list index out of range

and I don't know why, any help?

```
for x in range(0,9):
    print("Enter user: ",x)
    y = []
    y.append(input())        
for z in range(0,9):      
    print(y[z])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are resetting `y` on every iteration of your first loop by calling `y = []`.

Change it to:

```
y = []
for x in range(0,9):
    print("Enter user: ",x)
    y.append(input())        
for z in range(0,9):      
    print(y[z])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating `y` in every iteration, do this instead:

```py
y = []
for x in range(9):
    print("Enter user: ",x)
    y.append(input())        
for z in range(9):      
    print(y[z])
```

Plus, you can change the last loop to this

```py
print('\n'.join(y))
```